# Is the term "next consecutive" redundant in this sentence?

Tags: phrases, redundancy

Is the term "next consecutive" redundant in the following sentence? :

> "This movie will be the next consecutive movie in the series."

Referring to the most recent movie that will be released in a series.

Comment: What's "reduant"?

Comment: That refers to a type of pseudo-English when one tries to type too fast.

Comment: You don't need "consecutive". The next in a series IS consecutive. You REALLY don't want to say "movie" twice. "This will be the latest movie in the series" is fine. Or "This movie will be the latest in the series."